# How do I add a new package?

Tags: amber-smalltalk

How do I add a new package in the current IDE?

I do not see a button for adding a package.

This is on MSWindows 7 with Firefox 23.

To start the amber server I had opened a command window and then I navigated to the amber directory.

```
 C:\Users\User\Documents\amber-master>bin\amber serve
 Starting file server on http://127.0.0.1:4000
```

Comment: Which Amber version are you using and which Browser/OS? I can not reproduce this problem with Amber v0.11.0 and latest master (commit: `834ecb8c4afc24e057eb9f5b973101bf5e7abea5`) on OS X 10.6.8 in both Firefox 24.0 and Chrome 29. Tested with current IDE and the new Helios IDE.

Comment: Since you seem to start using Amber for a project it is likely that more questions arise. In this case I would like to invite you to join our mailinglist or IRC channel and tell us about your progress and/or arising issues. See http://amber-lang.net for details.

Comment: Thanks for posting this to the mailinglist. The server.bat file has been removed in favor of the `bin/amber.bat serve`command.

Comment: I have added the bin\amber.bat command to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new class in a new package add the following code snippet in the browser

```
    Object subclass: #MyClass
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    package: 'MyPackage'
```

and hit save. This works in the very latest amber. Not in the one two weeks before.
https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber

5th September 2013

**Addition**

The new packages created will be in the amber namespace which is not recommended. To have your own name space for your amber application use these instructions [Writing my first amber app](https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/wiki/Writing-my-first-app). It shows the directory layout to have your own name space.

[How to load amber](https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/wiki/How-to-load-amber) shows how to configure amber to use your own namespace.

Comment: Yes, this is how it should be done. What you encountered was a bug in the development version due to making Amber packages loadable with require.js.